# decode method returns unicode response in lambda env

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.7

Decode function in Python 3.7 environment in aws lambda returns `1\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000001` at [1] while in local python 3.7.2 interpretter it returns 101

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    data = b'1\x00\x00\x00\x0001'
    response = data.decode()
    print(response)#[1]
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': str(response)
    }
```

while local interpretter,

```
>>> data = b'1\x00\x00\x00\x0001'
>>> print (data.decode())
101
```

I require `101` as the response from the lambda 3.7 interpreter as well.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: try `data.decode("utf8")`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I get the same response 1\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000001 with utf-8 parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the null values (\x00) in the string. Print won't be able to output correctly if you have those null values in your string.

```
data.decode('utf8').replace('\x00', '')
```

Comment: Thanks!! I now understand why lambda returned /u0000 since \u0000 == \x00 == null which isn't visible in print :)